# How to concat rows in a groupby but keep all variables in Hive

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, impala

Let's say I have the following Minimal, Reproducible, Example (I am using Hive):

```
CREATE TABLE have (id INT, sub_id INT, name STRING, sub_name STRING, value STRING, A STRING, B STRING, C STRING);
INSERT INTO have VALUES
    (1,111111,'ITEM1','Score','AAA','concat1_1','concat2_1','concat3_1'),
    (1,111111,'ITEM1','Score','AAA','concat1_2','concat2_2','concat3_2'),
    (1,111111,'ITEM1','Weight','2+','conc1_1','conc2_1','conc3_1'),
    (1,111111,'ITEM1','Weight','2+','conc1_2','conc2_2','conc3_2'),
    (1,222222,'ITEM1','Score','BBB','c1_1','c2_1','c3_1'),
    (1,222222,'ITEM1','Score','BBB','c1_2','c2_2','c3_2')
    ;
```

I want to concatenate `a`, `b` and `c` accross rows with the same `sub_id` and `sub_name`

Using the `concat_ws` and a `group by` I can concatenate accross row:

```
create table want as
select sub_id, sub_name, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(a)) as a,
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(b)) as b,
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(c)) as c
from have
group by sub_id, sub_name;
```

But how can I retrieve also the other columns?

When I try

```
create table want as
select id, sub_id, name, sub_name, value, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(a)) as a, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(b)) as b, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(c)) as c
from have
group by sub_id, sub_name;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: line 17:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'id'
```

My desired output would be:

```
+----+--------+-------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+--+
| id | sub_id | name  | subname | value |          a          |          b          |          c          |  |  |
+----+--------+-------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+--+
|  1 | 111111 | ITEM1 | Score   | AAA   | concat1_1|concat1_2 | concat2_1|concat2_2 | concat3_1|concat3_2 |  |  |
|  1 | 111111 | ITEM1 | Weight  | 2+    | conc1_1|conc1_2     | conc2_1|conc2_2     |   conc3_1|conc3_2   |  |  |
|  1 | 222222 | ITEM1 | Score   | BBB   | c1_1|c1_2           |   c2_1|c2_2         |      c3_1|c3_2      |  |  |
+----+--------+-------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+--+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using aggregate function need to add non-group by column in `group by`

```
select id, sub_id, name, sub_name, value, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(a)) as a, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(b)) as b, 
   concat_ws("|", collect_set(c)) as c
from have
group by id, sub_id, name, sub_name, value;
```

Comment: This can't work, the `ON` at the end will return 0 results as there is no `sub_id` matching `sub_name`. Even with `t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id and t1.sub_name = t2.sub_name` I get duplicates.

Comment: @legends1337 Sorry I review your sample data you add column in `group by` might enough